# Entity Framework - Generic GetAll by List<string>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I have the following generic Get method using entity framework:

```
public TEntity Get(string id)
{
   using (var db = CreateContext())
   {
      return db.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
   }
}
```

Is there any possiblity to implement the same generic functionality with a list of ids?
Like that:

```
public List<TEntity> Get(List<string> ids)
{
   using (var db = CreateContext())
   {
      //???
   }
}
```

Comment: that's weird. But you might end up calling the previous method and return the whole list, something like `aList.Add(Get(id))`

Comment: why is it weird? Is there no possiblility to say something like .Where(x => ids.Contains(x.PrimaryKey))?

Comment: I'm not sure though, then after the where?

Comment: I don't understand. What "after the where"? After the where there should be a ToList